# Using NSRange rangeOfString

Tags: objective-c, cs193p

Can someone explain what location and length represent for NSRange.
If I use it in this context

```
NSRange range = [self.display.text rangeOfString:@"."];
if(range.location == NSNotFound){
self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
```

What does the location represent and can someone explain this code. Also where can I find more information on properties such as location> I found it in the header file as an NSUInteger but it doesn't describe what location actually does.

Comment: [NSRange in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html):

> `rangeofString` is used to finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string within the receiver.
>
> The index of the first occurrence within your original string will be stored in the `location` attribute of *`NSRange`*. In case there is no occurence found the method will return `NSNotFound`.

So your code will append the string your are testing with '.' if this character was not found in it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. It makes more sense now. Basically the location is trying to find the "." in my self.text.display and if it does find a "." then it won't add another one but if it doesn't find the "." in my display then it will append this string to the end of the display.

Comment: You are welcome please validate my answer or driis one whoever you feel best answered to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `location` field is the location, or index, of the NSRange - in your case it is the index of the string "." within the original string.
The `length` field is the length of the range that the `NSRange` implements.

You can also find the definition in the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) docs.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me.